# How do I update my Spyder version 3.3.6 launch icon?

Tags: bash, anaconda, spyder, debian-based, crostini

A few weeks ago, I installed Anaconda and Spyder 3.1.3 on my Pixelbook's Debian/Crostini VM. A few days ago, I upgraded to Spyder 3.3.6  Since I'm new to Spyder, I tried to keep the original installation as user-friendly as possible by using Anaconda and Package Manager.  See the code I used to update Spyder below:

```
#upgrade Spyder
# https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases
$ conda update qt pyqt
conda install spyder=3.3.6
```

Issue: Clicking the Spyder launch icon still opens the old 3.1.3 version.  How do I update the icon to launch version 3.3.6?  Also, I do not need the old version... should I uninstall it?  If so, how?

Typing "spyder" in the terminal launches version 3.3.6, while typing "spyder3" in the terminal launches version 3.1.3.

```
(conda_env) jaromf@penguin:~$ spyder3
(conda_env) jaromf@penguin:~$ spyder
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-jaromf'
```

BTW - only "spyder" version 3.3.6 returns the XDG_RUNTIME... line (could this be related to the issue?)

Comment: It seems you have two Spyder versions installed, one with `apt-get` (3.1.3) and one with Anaconda (3.3.6). To avoid this problem you should uninstall the `apt-get` version.

Comment: '$ sudo apt-get remove spyder3'

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you for the help! `$ sudo apt-get remove spyder3` successfully removed the old 3.1.3 version while not disturbing the newer 3.3.6 version.  The old icon was also automatically removed.  Since I usually open spyder from the terminal, I'm not too concerned about creating an icon for the 3.3.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

`$ sudo apt-get remove spyder3` successfully removed the old 3.1.3 version while not disturbing the newer 3.3.6 version. The old icon was also automatically removed. Since I usually open spyder from the terminal, I'm not too concerned about creating an icon for the 3.3.6 version